# CSS strange appear of color in link

Tags: html, css

I am creating a few HTML pages and I want the navigation link to the current page to have different styling than the rest of the links. However my current solution is not producing the desired result.

This is my code:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.current{
   color: #0078fe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}

a:active {
    color: #0078fe;
}
```

But this has the following results:

Home:

[image: home page]

About:

[image: about page]

How can I style the correct link to the current page with the `current` styling without applying to the other links?

Comment: `:visited` is another pseudo selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Comment: I think :visited does not matter in this case

Comment: Do you mean you want the page you are currently on to be bold?

Comment: Hard to tell without more code, but do both pages have that `.current` class applied to both `li` elements? Also, I wonder if there is something changing the font-weight of one of the `a` tags, but I'd have to dig around in the browser tools to see. The thing that comes to mind first is something applied to `a:visited` but it sounds like you've ruled that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-agent (browser) default styling for the link itself (the `a` element) is overwriting your styles because the link styles of the user-agent have a higher specificity to the actual element being styled, as your `.current` selector is selecting the list item that is the parent of the link and are only applying some styles to their children through inheritance.

*If you want the link to only be bold on the `active` state, then you need to have the font-weight`property changed on the`active` selector, as I have done in the examples below.*

What you want to do is give a class to the links themselves (the `a` elements) and put the properties on those. Could use a class name like `.nav-link`. I am assuming that `.current` is meant to just be on whatever the link for whatever the current page is. Like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link current" href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.nav-link {
   color: #0078fe;
}

.nav-link:hover {
   color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:active {
   color: #0078fe;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you meant `.current` as a class for the link of the current page the user is on, you could also use the `:not()` selector to keep the `hover` and `active` states from applying to the "link" for the current page, the one with the `.current` class applied. Like so:

```css
.nav-link {
   color: #0078fe;
}

.nav-link:not(.current):hover {
   color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:not(.current):active {
   color: #0078fe;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

While keeping selectors simple and just applying a class to all the `a` elements like above is a better practice, alternately you could continue to have a class on each `li` element and then use a descendant combination selector.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="nav-link current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.nav-link > a {
   color: #0078fe;
}

.nav-link > a:hover {
   color: #fff;
}

.nav-link > a:active {
  color: #0078fe;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

It looks like what you actually are asking is to style a link in a nav differently when you are on the page the link is for. You do this by applying a class to the link for the page you are on, as I did above by using the '.current' class. The [:active state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) has nothing to do with that, and I think that why I and others did not initially understand you. What you are going to want to do is this:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link current" href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.nav-link {
   color: #0078fe;
}

.nav-link:not(.current):hover {
   color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:not(.current):active {
   color: #0078fe;
}

.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here you have the `nav-link` classes on the actual `a` elements themselves, the current page also gets the `current` class on its link. You set the color for the link, and the current and active states while keeping the current link from getting the hover/active states using the `not()` combination selector. Finally we  say that anything with the `.current` class gets bolded. Just add the `current` selector to the HTML of each page's respective link. If it is a Single Page Application then you can use JavaScript to apply the class when a link is clicked. If you have anymore questions, just let me know!

Comment: Hello Stephen! I still can't fix the thing, so if maybe I was not understandable I just want to make active link bolded. I tried just put font-weight in :active but nothing happened.

Comment: Then add `font-weight: bold` to the `active` state of the link

Comment: @virus-distribution-center check my edit. The code there should work for you now and explain why yours wasn't working.

Comment: @virus-distribution-center just checking here, but you understand what the active state is right? The state is activated only while a button is being pressed down, or activated. When the effect is on a link that takes you to a different page you will only see it for a few milliseconds. Generally the effect lasts no longer than the duration a mouse button is in the down position during a single mouse click. It does **NOT** mean that the link is the current active page. Please [check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: @virus-distribution-center OK, now that I understand what you need check the edit marked with  at the bottom of my post. It shows you what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply styling to the link to the page you're currently on, you need to detect which page you're currently on and compare that against the `href` attribute of each `a` tag and give the class name `current` to the one whose `href` matches the page location (url). This cannot be done with CSS alone.

**Server-Side Rendering**

If you're using server-side rendering (or just static HTML pages), you can just only put the `current` CSS class to the correct link.

So in `main.html` you'll have:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in `about.html` you'll have:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Client-Side Rendering**

If you're using client-side rendering (or are looking for a more dynamic, less manual solution), you can detect the path of the current page and then set the `current` CSS class on the right `a` tag using JavaScript.

Note for this solution, I'd recommend putting the `current` class on the `a` directly (rather than the `li`), however you can work around that pretty easily.

For example:

```js
const currentPathname = document.location.pathname;

const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

links.forEach(link => {
    if (link.pathname == currentPathname) {
        link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
        link.classList.remove("current"); // possibly optional
    }
})
```

A working example:

```js
const currentPathname = document.location.pathname;

const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

links.forEach(link => {
    if (link.pathname == currentPathname) {
        link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
        link.classList.remove("current"); // possibly optional
    }
})
```

```css
a.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/js">This Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Another Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply style on anchor tag. like `.active a`.
On Home pae assign `.active` class to

`<li><a class="active" href="main.html">Home</a></li>` and on about page assign `.active` class to `<li><a class="active" href="about.html">About</a></li>`

```css
.current a{
   color: #0078fe;
   font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
   color: white;
}

a:active {
   color: #0078fe;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```